# SUM list members in PROLOG

Tags: prolog

I'm new to prolog and trying to do a sum of a list, for example:

```
a(1,2,3).
a(2,3,4).
a(4,5,6).
a(7,8,9).

rule1(SUM) :-
    findall([X,Y,Z], a(X,Y,Z), LIST),
    sum(LIST,SUM).
```

I tried with sum(LIST,SUM) and will return an undefined error regarding the sum predicate.

I want to create the LIST that will look like `[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]` and add every single number inside, so total will be 1+2+3+2+3+4+4+5+6+7+8+9

Comment: SORTED.. it just has to go with lists without sublist. like LIST=[X,Y,Z,C,E,T,C] NOT LIST=[[X,Y,Z].[E,T,C]. so rule(SUMTOTAL):- findall(X,a(X,Y,Z),LIST), sum[LIST,SUM1], findall(Y,a(X,Y,Z),LIST2), sum[LIST2,SUM2],findall(Z,a(X,Y,Z),LIST3), sum[LIST3,SUM3], SUMTOTAL is SUM+SUM2+SUM3.

Comment: Can use definition at https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/04239b9f40e0b7f40219ef835991995036f43b08/library/lists.pl#L581 , as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Using the swi-prolog predicates [findall/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3) and [sum_list/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sum_list/2):

```
?- findall(W, (a(X,Y,Z), W is X+Y+Z), L), sum_list(L, S).
L = [6, 9, 15, 24],
S = 54.
```

So, you can define:

```
total(S) :-
    findall(W, (a(X,Y,Z), W is X+Y+Z), L), 
    sum_list(L, S).
```

And ask:

```
?- total(S).
S = 54.
```

Comment: thx for this ... you gave me a better ideea and now my code is half than it used to be with my version !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explicitly create the list of lists you show in the question, you can do (using SWI Prolog)

```
total_1(S):-
    findall([A,B,C], a(A,B,C), L), % L contains the list of lists
    flatten(L,LS),
    sum_list(LS,S).
```

An alternative is to use `maplist/3` (however maplist can be difficult to grasp if you are a beginner)

```
total_2(S):-
    findall([A,B,C], a(A,B,C), L),
    maplist(sum_list,L,LS),
    sum_list(LS,S).
```

In both cases,

```
?- total_2(S).
S = 54
?- total_1(S).
S = 54
```

Comment: thx for answer, i will look into your version as well, hope will open my mind understanding prolog better! ty